# How to read a txt file, stored in a google storage bucket, from a cloud function, in node

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I've written some node.js code which is sitting in the source of a Cloud Function.  When it runs I want to read a text file from a google storage bucket, and process it.

The Code runs fine when running locally, but for some reason doesn't work when running in the Cloud Function.  I would expect something written out from the console logs.

I can't see any errors, as I thought it might be a permissions problem (might be looking in the wrong place though).

Any ideas?

The awaits and async's were just because I wanted it to wait for the response before continuing, but that seems to have no effect on it either.

```
  const fileName = 'testData.txt';
  const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
  const storage = new Storage();
  const bucket = storage.bucket('my_bucket_name');
  const remoteFile = bucket.file(fileName);

  await remoteFile.download(async function(err, contents) {
       console.log("file err: "+err);  
       console.log("file data: "+contents);
  });
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the entire code of the deployed function, and be clear about what your destination is.  Include any errors from the console log.  Without context, we have no idea what's going wrong. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Do you expect to run your function with an HTTP trigger?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to verify that the [runtime account](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/function-identity#runtime_service_account) for the function has the necessary permissions to access the bucket. In general the runtime account is `PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com` and add at least the ***Storage Object Viewer*** (you can check more roles [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles#standard-roles)).

Then, test the function again. If something goes wrong, please check the logs of the function.

**EDIT**

Not sure, but maybe seems to be something with the code. I've used the following to test the function and works perfect:

*index.js*:

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage();
const bucket = storage.bucket('bucket_name');
const fileName = 'test.txt';
const remoteFile = bucket.file(fileName);

exports.helloWorld = (req, res) => {

    console.log('Reading File');
    var archivo = remoteFile.createReadStream();

    console.log('Concat Data');
    var  buf = '';
    archivo.on('data', function(d) {
        buf += d;
    }).on('end', function() {
        console.log(buf);
        console.log("End");
        res.send(buf);
    });     
};
```

*package.json*:

```
{
    "name": "sample-http",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "dependencies": {
        "@google-cloud/storage": "^4.7.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Fernando, I've added the permission as you suggested, and rerun the function.

All I get is the following in the logs

`2020-04-03 09:44:53.221 BSTprocess-customer-file58en4g3hgcj4 Function execution started`

`2020-04-03 09:44:54.319 BSTprocess-customer-file58en4g3hgcj4 Running Option 2`

`2020-04-03 09:44:54.430 BSTprocess-customer-file58en4g3hgcj4 Function execution took 1209 ms, finished with status: 'ok'`

No errors at all

Comment: I added the comment to ensure the code was running

I added a log to prove it was calling the code, so it looks like this.

  `console.log("Running Option 2")

  await remoteFile.download(async function(err, contents) {

    console.log("file err: "+err);  

    console.log("file data: "+contents); 

  });`

Comment: Please check the `EDIT`  in the response

Answer (score 1):

async function readStorageFile(obj){

```
try{
    obj.Result = ''
    if (obj.filename===undefined) return

    bucket = gcs.bucket('gs:yourinfo');
    //Get File
    await bucket.file(obj.filename).download()
   .then(async data => {
       obj.data = data
      obj.Result = 'OK'
      return
  }) 
.catch(err => {
      return
})
return
```

}
catch (err){
return
}
}

obj = {filename:'TEST1.json'}
await readStorageFile(obj,'testing')
if (obj.Result==='OK') { console.log('obj.data='+obj.data) }
else { console.log('Not Found')}
return

Comment: Beside your code, your answer would benefit from also explaining what the person did wrong.

Comment: Also, your code has a top level return statement that is not contained by any function.